# What are the real damage figures of defensive buildings?

Tags: clash-of-clans

When viewing a defensive building (and unit statistics), it will show how much damage per second the building/unit does. Considering the cannon only shoots every 2/3 seconds, does that mean cannon damage x 2/3?

Comment: In CoC turrets and troops do not have the actual damage/heal stats. You have to rely on Wiki to get the actual damage done and the time interval. In boom beach you can get everything in the info, hope they add this to CoC too.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

DPS means Damage Per Second.

*DPS=DamageMadeByOneShot/NumberOfShotsEverySecond*

So, a mortar with x DPS would one-shot an archer with 3x points of life, if shooting every 3 seconds.